# Alias for recent log files

Tags: bash, shell-script, date

Usually when I'm searching the logs, its for something that happened recently. I end up tabbing at bash prompt to complete the names.

I finally did bash alias that uses date arithmetic to build the file name. Something like following

```
grep <test> `date '+localhost_access_log.%C%y-%2m-%2d.txt' -d "-3 days"` grep 400 `date '+localhost_access_log.%C%y-%2m-%2d.txt' -d "-2 days"` grep 400 `date '+localhost_access_log.%C%y-%2m-%2d.txt' -d "-1 days"` grep 400 `date '+localhost_access_log.%C%y-%2m-%2d.txt' -d "-0 days"`
```

Is there anyway to optimize this? Ideally I would like to create multiple aliases to grep through most recent three files like localhost_access_log.2019-06-24.txt or api-2019-06-24-1.log and don't like date command code duplication. Essentially looking for help for a bash function that will return 4 most recent file names based on the pattern I send including today's log file and can be passed to grep command

Answer (score 1):

If you don't insist on `bash`, you can do this quite easily in `zsh` using `setopt extendedglob`:

`grep <test> *(ND.om[1,4])`

will grep through the four most recent files in the current directory.

Explanation:

- `N` - turn on "null glob" (silently substitute nothing if the glob pattern doesn't match)
- `D` - turn on "GLOB_DOTS" (also match "hidden files")
- `.` - match plain files
- `om` - order by modification time
- `[1-4]` - array subscript

A pure bash solution could be something like

`grep test $(ls -1rt | tail -n 4)`

(But this will fail on funky filenames, such as ones with embedded spaces.)

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "pattern" -mtime -1 -exec grep test {} +`

Will grep through files in the current directory whose name matches `pattern` and which have been modified within the last day (this could be more than four, but it could also be zero). It'll work on funky filenames, though.

Comment: From `bash` (or any other shell):  `zsh -c 'grep -e "$1" *(ND.om[1,4])' zsh "<test>"`

Comment: zsh is installed by default on ubuntu boxes - or at least its not installed on the servers I checked. Being a production boxes, I'll have to provide justifications and will probably be laughed at for this request

Comment: I'd say increased productivity is good justification. :) There are many other `zsh` features that increase productivity. Why not give it a try? `zsh` has no esoteric dependencies and installing it won't break anything, just make the lives of people who know how to use it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple `bash`-based solution.  It works by using `ls` to list the N most recent files matching a given wildcard, on the assumption that each log file is for a single day:

```
$ grep test $(ls -tr localhost_access_log.*.txt | tail -4)
```

If that counts as an unwise case of parsing the output of ls, then use this instead:

```
$ grep test $(find . -name localhost_access_log.\*.txt -mtime -3d)
```

In general, the point is to avoid getting tangled up in the date arithmetic.  Just run `grep` on the N most recent files.  Again, this assumes that your logs rotate once per day, as your question suggests.

Comment: L, the reason why I went for dates is second log file name example I gave. There will be multiple files having that date api-2019-06-24-1.log or api-2019-06-24-25.log as some log files split based on the size. I have to look for certain dates and not just latest files

Comment: @user871199 Then the `find` version of the command may be the most useful to you.  That will catch all log files <= N days old.

Comment: It will still fail on filenames with embedded spaces. Better use `find ... -exec grep test {} ++`.

Comment: Granted, but from the OP it is known that they don't: `date '+localhost_access_log.%C%y-%2m-%2d.txt'`